# "D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile" Getting it to work or finding an alterative

Tags: c++, directx

I'm pretty new to DirectX, I'm trying to get some sample code I found online to work. Apparently it needs D3DX11tex.h and D3DX11.lib, but it always says it can't open the header. I've tried using CreateWICTextureFromFile, but I don't really know what I'm doing, any help would be appreciated. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

All of D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 are deprecated, along with a few other aspects of the legacy DirectX SDK. You can continue to use them in classic Win32 desktop apps with VS 2012 or later / Windows 8.x SDK / Windows 10 SDK but you must add the DirectX SDK include/libs appropriately and use them with care. This is covered in detail on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). See also [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/).

There are a number of options for [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/), and it's recommended that new applications minimize or avoid use of the legacy DirectX SDK as much as possible. The only cases that make sense to needing the legacy DirectX SDK are covered in detail in [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk/)--other than someone learning from all the various outdated books and online tutorials for DirectX 11.

The `CreateWICTextureFromFile` function in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) is a good solution that doesn't require the legacy Directx SDK at all, and is documented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader). It's also covered in this [tutorial series](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

> Keep in mind that the D3DX11 texture loaders were also "everything and the kitchen sink" implementations. The [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) library supports all kinds of legacy loaders, format conversion, resizing, etc. that was supported by D3DX11. For runtime use, however, [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) is a much faster, leaner, more elegant solution assuming you can do any required legacy conversions at build-time. See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/04/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression/).